# Alphanumeric sorting for 3 different values

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a list in excel which has the following values: CTP315-07-01, CTP315-07-51, CTP315-07-220. Excel doesn't sort the values properly so I'm trying to make a script which does that. My code runs, but it doesn't do anything for some reason. Here it is. Does anyone know how I would sort this?

```
Sub test()
Dim minValue As Integer
Dim minIndex As Integer
For i = 238 To 401
    tmp = i
    For j = i + 1 To 401
        Dim w As Integer
        Dim k As Integer
        x = Right(Cells(j, 45).Value, 3)
        y = Right(Cells(tmp, 45).Value, 3)
        If Left(x, 1) = "-" Then
            x = Right(x, 2)
            If Left(x, 1) = "0" Then
                x = Right(x, 1)
            End If
        End If
        If Left(y, 1) = "-" Then
            y = Right(y, 2)
            If Left(y, 1) = "0" Then
                y = Right(y, 1)
            End If
        End If
        w = ConvertToInteger(x) 'this is the first value (j, 45)
        k = ConvertToInteger(y) 'this is the 2nd value (tmp,45)
        If w < k Then
            tmp = j
        End If
    Next j
    temp = Cells(i, 45)
    Cells(i, 45) = Cells(tmp, 45)
    Cells(tmp, 45) = temp
Next i

End Sub

Function ConvertToInteger(v1 As Variant) As Integer
On Error GoTo 100:
    ConvertInteger = CInt(v1)
    Exit Function
100:
 MsgBox "Failed to convert """ & v1 & """ to an integer.", , "Aborting - Failed Conversion"
 End
End Function
```

Comment: use text to columns, split on the `-` and then sort the three columns.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't sort them properly"? A simple sort will list them in ascending alpha-numeric order, so what order do you want them sorted into?

Comment: So right now this is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/L1hfY    It skips 11 through 51 and goes straight to 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following, it will take the value after the - and convert that to an integer, add that integer to the adjacent column, AT in this case and then sort that column:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 45).End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column B

For i = 2 To LastRow 'loop from row 2 to last
    TrimText = ws.Cells(i, 45) 'get the value from cell to be trimmed
    NewValue = Left(TrimText, 6) 'get the first 6 characters
    ws.Cells(i, 46) = NewValue 'add that text to adjecent column AT

    SecondValue = NewValue & "-" 'get the mid values
    SecondValue = Trim(Replace(TrimText, SecondValue, "")) 'remove the first value from string
    newpos = InStrRev(SecondValue, "-") 'find the second - dash
    SecondValue = Left(SecondValue, newpos - 1) 'remove anything after the dash
    ws.Cells(i, 47) = CInt(SecondValue) 'convert to Integer
    pos = InStrRev(TrimText, "-") 'find the last - in text
    If pos > 0 Then 'if found
        NewValue = Right(TrimText, Len(TrimText) - pos) 'remove anything before dash -
        ws.Cells(i, 48) = CInt(NewValue) 'convert value to integer, add that value to adjecent column AT
    End If
Next i
ws.Cells.AutoFilter 'add filter

'below sort by column AT = 46
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AT1:AT" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AU1:AU" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AV1:AV" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
ws.Columns("AT:AV").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft 'delete the columns used to sort
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to be able to do it using only one column. By boss doesn't want columns being used for this purpose -.-.

Comment: Updated my answer, so it will use them three columns to sort and then delete them... Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working is because you have a typo.

In case you are unaware of it, there is a line of code: `Option Explicit` which, if inserted at the top of your module, will require all variables used to be defined. This is really useful for catching typos in variable names.

There are also some tricks with debugging. A short-cut to open the code editor (on Windows) is `Alt+F11`. Once there, you can use the `F8` key to step through your code one line at a time. You can also set breakpoints in code by clicking to the left of the line of code you want to break (or pause) on.

Usually, it's preferred for people, when possible, to identify on which line of code the issue is occurring at.

When I stepped through your code, I was able to identify the problematic lines in your test module as being these:

```
w = ConvertToInteger(x) 'this is the first value (j, 45)
k = ConvertToInteger(y) 'this is the 2nd value (tmp,45)
```

because the `w` and `k` were always both `0` after these lines - even when they shouldn't have been.

This lead me to the conclusion that your `ConvertToInteger` Function is not actually returning anything.

I would recommend taking a closer look at the below line of code, and checking for typos:

```
ConvertInteger = CInt(v1)
```

**Clarification:**

For a function to return a variable, it needs to be assigned a value.

```
Function plusTwo ()
   plusTwo = 2 + 2 'plusTwo needs to match the name of the function otherwise it will be interpreted as a new variable
End Function
```

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if you'll get any other bugs from having `End
End Function` at the end of the `ConvertToInteger` Function